# how add a column to a data.frame with the occurence number of an another column

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the following data.frame

```
   x y   
1 t1 5                  
2 t2 2   
3 t2 7  
4 t3 9  
5 t1 6
```

how add  a column with the occurence number of the value in the first column like below  ?:

```
   x y occ  
1 t1 5 1  
2 t2 2 1  
3 t2 7 2  
4 t3 9 1  
5 t1 6 2
```

Comment: Have you searched for `rle` under the `r` tag here?

Comment: I don't know how to use rle to compute the occurence column i need, could you give me an example ?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10029235/cumulative-count-in-r

Comment: See at least [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8997638/numbering-by-groups) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11370548/episode-count-for-each-row).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not 100% sure but is this what you mean?

```
> my.df <- data.frame(x=c("t1","t2","t2","t3","t1"), y=c(5,2,7,9,6))
> my.df <- data.frame(x=my.df$x,
+                     y=my.df$y,
+                     occ=sapply(1:nrow(my.df), function(i) sum(my.df$x[1:i] == my.df$x[i])))

> my.df
   x y occ
1 t1 5   1
2 t2 2   1
3 t2 7   2
4 t3 9   1
5 t1 6   2
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `sequence` and `rle` on your sorted `data.frame`:

```
my.df <- data.frame(x=c("t1","t2","t2","t3","t1"), y=c(5,2,7,9,6))
# Order by x
my.df = my.df[order(my.df$x), ]
my.df$occ = sequence(rle(as.vector(my.df$x))$lengths)
my.df
#    x y occ
# 1 t1 5   1
# 5 t1 6   2
# 2 t2 2   1
# 3 t2 7   2
# 4 t3 9   1
# Uncomment if you want to go back to original row order
# my.df[order(rownames(my.df)), ]
```

## Update: Something I learned today

I had seen, but not used the `ave` function. Looks like you can do this without reordering your original `data.frame`:

```
my.df$occ = ave(as.numeric(my.df$x), as.numeric(my.df$x), FUN=seq_along)
```

Comment: Son of pup that's nice.  I knew you could use `ave` somehow but was trying `sum` rather than `seq_along`.  Nice +1

Comment: Ahh now I got it you can do it with cumsum too: `ave(rep(1, length(my.df$x)), as.numeric(my.df$x), FUN=cumsum)`

Comment: I was pretty excited about finding it too.... But I have a question: Is it only a "pup" because I pretty much just re-posted an already available solution? ;-)

Comment: I was trying to keep it PG for the kids. Plus you can shorten it even more to: `ave(rep(1, length(my.df$x)), my.df$x, FUN=cumsum)`

Comment: Nice. I'll look at this (`ave`, at least.... not this problem) more in the morning. Using R near midnight in warm and sticky India doesn't always compute nicely.