# R: add a dplyr group label as a number

Tags: r, dplyr, grouping

I can not get my head around this must be simple task. How to get a group label as a consecutive number.

```
library(dplyr)
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(id = sample(c('a','b'), 20, T),
                 name = sample(c('N1', 'N2', 'N3'), 20, T),
                 val = runif(20)) %>%
  group_by(id) %>% 
  arrange(id, name)
```

What I want is a label `group_no` that indicates the number of categories of the variable `name` within each `id` dplyr group. I can not find a solution in the dplyr package itself. Something like this:

```
# A tibble: 20 x 4
# Groups:   id [2]
   id    name     val group_no
   <fct> <fct>  <dbl>     <int>
 1 a     N1    0.647          1
 2 a     N1    0.530          1
 3 a     N1    0.245          1
 4 a     N2    0.693          2
 5 a     N2    0.478          2
 6 a     N2    0.861          2
 7 a     N3    0.821          3
 8 a     N3    0.0995         3
 9 a     N3    0.662          3
10 b     N1    0.553          1
11 b     N1    0.0233         1
12 b     N1    0.519          1
13 b     N2    0.783          2
14 b     N2    0.789          2
15 b     N2    0.477          2
16 b     N2    0.438          2
17 b     N2    0.407          2
18 b     N3    0.732          3
19 b     N3    0.0707         3
20 b     N3    0.316          3
```

Note, that the values of `name` could be anything and certainly are not normally suffixed by a number as in the example (otherwise I could do `sub("^N", "", df$name)`.

I am looking for something a little different than the  `1:n()` solution in SO posts such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8997638/numbering-by-groups?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: `group_indices(df, name)`, but unfortunately [`group_indices` doesn't work inside `mutate`](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/1185)...You find some workarounds in the post though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think in this case something as simple as :

```
df %>%
  mutate(group_no = as.integer(name))
```

will work

```
# A tibble: 20 x 4
# Groups:   id [2]
   id    name     val group_no
   <fct> <fct>  <dbl>    <int>
 1 a     N1    0.647         1
 2 a     N1    0.530         1
 3 a     N1    0.245         1
 4 a     N2    0.693         2
 5 a     N2    0.478         2
 6 a     N2    0.861         2
 7 a     N3    0.821         3
 8 a     N3    0.0995        3
 9 a     N3    0.662         3
10 b     N1    0.553         1
11 b     N1    0.0233        1
12 b     N1    0.519         1
13 b     N2    0.783         2
14 b     N2    0.789         2
15 b     N2    0.477         2
16 b     N2    0.438         2
17 b     N2    0.407         2
18 b     N3    0.732         3
19 b     N3    0.0707        3
20 b     N3    0.316         3
```

Comment: That is such a nice trick!

Comment: thanks! It is actually a recurrent mistake i make :)

Comment: Nice - but only works with factors (as in my example). I tend not to want factors.

Comment: @user3375672 indeed. But you could do `mutate(group_no = as.integer(as.factor(name)))` in that case, it would still work

Comment: Sure - good point. I will accept this for its simplicity though the other suggestions work just as fine.

Answer (score 5):

We can do

```
df %>%
   group_by(id) %>%
   mutate(group_no = cumsum(c(TRUE, name[-1] != name[-n()])))
```

---

Or with `match`

```
df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(group_no = match(name, unique(name)))
# A tibble: 20 x 4
# Groups:   id [2]
#   id    name     val group_no
#   <fct> <fct>  <dbl>    <int>
# 1 a     N1    0.647         1
# 2 a     N1    0.530         1
# 3 a     N1    0.245         1
# 4 a     N2    0.693         2
# 5 a     N2    0.478         2
# 6 a     N2    0.861         2
# 7 a     N3    0.821         3
# 8 a     N3    0.0995        3
# 9 a     N3    0.662         3
#10 b     N1    0.553         1
#11 b     N1    0.0233        1
#12 b     N1    0.519         1
#13 b     N2    0.783         2
#14 b     N2    0.789         2
#15 b     N2    0.477         2
#16 b     N2    0.438         2
#17 b     N2    0.407         2
#18 b     N3    0.732         3
#19 b     N3    0.0707        3
#20 b     N3    0.316         3
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution that uses `left_join`.

```
df %>%
  left_join(df %>%
  group_by(id, name) %>%
  summarise(group_no = row_number()))
```